# Update table with subquery and duplicates

Tags: sql, oracle

I need to update a table based on another table, so I have the statement:

```
update FAULTS
set FAULTS.FAULT_STATE = (
    select INCIDENTS.TICKET_STATE from INCIDENTS
    where INCIDENTS.CF_ID = FAULTS.CF_ID
)
```

And it gives me error saying:

```
ORA-01427: single-row subquery returns more than one row
```

I tried DISTINCT but the state values are different too so DISTINCT does not work. So I changed it too:

```
update FAULTS
set FAULTS.FAULT_STATE = (
    select INCIDENTS.TICKET_STATE from INCIDENTS
    where INCIDENTS.CF_ID = FAULTS.CF_ID and rownum = 1
)
```

Now it does not give errors.

The problem is, if the sub-query returns a null, it will also update the row and clear the content. Any fix for that?

Comment: Incidentally, the `rownum` has no bearing on the fact that this SQL will update all rows in FAULTS (if it didn't error)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can ensure only rows with a match are updated like this:

```
update FAULTS
set FAULTS.FAULT_STATE = (
    select INCIDENTS.TICKET_STATE from INCIDENTS
    where INCIDENTS.CF_ID = FAULTS.CF_ID and rownum = 1
)
where exists (
    select INCIDENTS.TICKET_STATE from INCIDENTS
    where INCIDENTS.CF_ID = FAULTS.CF_ID
)
```

Answer (score 0):

merge variant (10g+):

```
merge into faults
using (select cf_id, ticket_state from incidents) incidents
   on (incidents.cf_id = faults.cf_id)
when matched then update
 set fault_state=ticket_state;
```

Comment: I tried and it gives me an error saying " cannot get a stable set of row", and I googled and they say its because of duplicate rows. I added another criteria : `on (incidents.cf_id = faults.cf_id and incidents.root_cause = 1)` but it tells me `root_cause is not a valid identifier`. What should I do?